# Customize Spring Boot launch script

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a typical Spring Boot `2.x` application. I'm currently deploying the application using Docker. I'm also using the built-in shell script that a "distribution" provides — when done via Gradle, read: `assembleBootDist`, `installBootDist`, etc.

The issue is that I have to execute **(a)** some other shell script before starting the application, **(b)** insert this shell script somehow the built-in one, **(c)** or something else that achieves the same.

So I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this in a clean way, without introducing any security concerns, etc. I've been trying to plug into the `bootStartScripts` (Gradle) task, but no luck there. I'm aware there is a `launchScript` property within `bootJar`, but as far as I can tell it replaces altogether the actual built-in script provided by Spring Boot — and I'm avoiding that.

Any other shell-fu would also work, provided nothing around security is compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another solution](https://github.com/docker-library/redmine/issues/52) could be to (still) use the shell script that provides the custom logic and then execute (in the end) the built-in shell script generated by the Spring Boot "distribution" (Gradle) task:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "%s\n" "Running some initialization steps..."
# ...

# This is the shell script generated by the Spring Boot "distribution" (Gradle) task
exec /path/to/application "$@"
```

Save this as, for instance: `docker-entrypoint`, and use it as usual in the `Dockerfile`'s `ENTRYPOINT` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hack but with spring boot default script customization provided - may be you can use "inlinedConfScript" ( explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M4/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization)) which basically points to a script meant to provide configuration but since it is a script file technically you can write scripting code as usual.

> inlinedConfScript
>
> Reference to a file script that should be inlined in the default
> launch script. This can be used to set environmental variables such as
> JAVA_OPTS before any external config files are loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `inlinedConfScript` looks very much what I was looking for, but I was under the impression this only apply to Spring Boot applications running as Unix/Linux services...but probably it also works for usual applications. Will post any updates on my end.